# Crontab, every 6+1 hours (not every 7 hours)

Tags: cron

If I set up my cron to be:

```
* */6 * * *
```

Then my understanding is, that it will run at every day at every hour that is divisible by 6, so:

```
06:00
12:00
18:00
24:00
```

Suppose I would like it to run it with a delay like 1 hour [pseudocode]:

```
* */6+1 * * *
```

or

```
06:00 + 01:00 = 07:00
12:00 + 01:00 = 13:00
18:00 + 01:00 = 19:00
24:00 + 01:00 = 01:00
```

How would I do that?

If I make it `*/7`:

```
* */7 * * *
```

It will run:

```
07:00
14:00
21:00
```

which is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different implementations of `cron`, so check the manual on your system by running `man 5 crontab` to confirm the format it supports.

Assuming you have the popular "Vixie cron", the format description includes the following:

> Step values can be used in conjunction with ranges.  Following a range with `/<number>` specifies skips of the number's value through the range.  For example, `0-23/2` can be used in the hours field to specify command execution every other hour (the alternative in the V7 standard is `0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22`).  Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you want to say `every two hours`, just use `*/2`.

And above that:

> A field may be an asterisk (*), which always stands for `first-last`.

So, `*/6` is actually short-hand for `0-23/6` - start at `0`, and continue in steps of 6 until we reach `23`, giving `0,6,12,18`. (Note that the hour field runs 0 to 23, not 1 to 24, as you've implied in the question.)

In this implementation, therefore, the sequence `1,7,13,19` can be written `1-23/6` (or `1-19/6`).

With a large skip, writing out the list in full (`1,7,13,19`) is arguably more readable, and should work on all versions of `cron`, but that's up to you.